# How use getFragmentManager() in adapter

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, fragmentmanager

How use getFragmentManager() in adapter. how use this code in adapter ? (I use this code in my SecondFragment).

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("OneFragment");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

And this way in adapter doesn't work :

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("OneFragment");
final FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

and show error to me :

```
Required:
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Found:
android.app.FragmentManage
```

in my Adapter (i need use `getFragmentManager()` in my adapter.) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

import me.bazaarche.Fragment.FilterFragment;
import me.bazaarche.Fragment.HomeFragment;
import me.bazaarche.app.R;

public class CategorySub1Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategorySub1Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private String[] categorySub1Name;
    int categoryPosition;
    int categorySub0Position;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    public CategorySub1Adapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, String[] categorySub1Name, int categoryPosition, int categorySub0Position) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categorySub1Name = categorySub1Name;
        this.categoryPosition = categoryPosition;
        this.categorySub0Position = categorySub0Position;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View categorySub1Menu;
        TextView categorySub1Name;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            categorySub1Menu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_sub0_menu);
            categorySub1Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_sub1_name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_category_sub1, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.categorySub1Name.setText(categorySub1Name[position]);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.open_menu);
        animation.setStartOffset(30 * position);
        holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);

        HomeFragment.adAdapter.ClearList();
        HomeFragment.last_ad_id = 0;
        FilterFragment.categoryPosition = categoryPosition;
        FilterFragment.categorySub0Position = categorySub0Position;
        FilterFragment.categorySub1Position = position;
        HomeFragment.adAdapter.LoadMore();

        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = fragmentManager.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("OneFragment");
        final FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frg);
        ft.attach(frg);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categorySub1Name.length;
    }
}
```

i need use `getFragmentManager()` in my adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your import to this :

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Try to change the `Framgnet` using this :

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("OneFragment");
final FragmentTransaction ft = ((Activity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: in Adapter `getActivity()` not available

Comment: in Adapter : after `this.context.` , `getSupportFragmentManager()` not available.

Comment: Show my your imports, and check if you have the imports that I've provided to you, thanks.

Comment: `getFragmentManager()` not available with `this.context.`

Comment: I misstyped... change it to `((Activity) context)`

Comment: show error to me :
`Incompatible types.
Required:
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Found:
android.app.Fragment`

Comment: You have to change your `Fragment` import, to this `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: my import is `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` but show to me `Incompatible types. Required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment Found: android.app.Fragment`

Comment: You have to change your Home and Filter Fragment I guess

Comment: they are my fragment in my viewpager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159852/discussion-between-skizo-oziks-and-arman-download).

Comment: and when change my import to android.app.Fragment; don't show error but when i run application crashed

Answer (score 0):

inside `onBindViewHolder()` method
you can use java equivalent of this kotlin code

```
val fm=(holder.itemView.context as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
```

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**changes in CategorySub1Adapter constructor.**

```
public CategorySub1Adapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, String[] categorySub1Name, int categoryPosition, int categorySub0Position) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categorySub1Name = categorySub1Name;
    this.categoryPosition = categoryPosition;
    this.categorySub0Position = categorySub0Position;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}
```

**to**

```
     private Context context;
     private Activity mActivity;

    public CategorySub1Adapter(Activity mActivity, FragmentManager fragmentManager, String[] categorySub1Name, int categoryPosition, int categorySub0Position) {
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
    this.categorySub1Name = categorySub1Name;
    this.categoryPosition = categoryPosition;
    this.categorySub0Position = categorySub0Position;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}
```

**Try to change**

```
mYourAdapter = new CategorySub1Adapter(getActivity(),........);
```

**and change this**

```
    Fragment frg = null;
    frg = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("OneFragment");
    final FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
```

**and if you want context**

```
 @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_category_sub1, parent, false);

    // get context
    context=parent.getContext();

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```